# Circular Array Population

Tags: c, arrays

I had a question about circular array population essentially my code prints out random data into a txt file call car_data. I was wondering if someone could help me understand why under the `add_it` and `write_it` functions i am using the `index%size`? under `ptr[<argument>]`. I also had a question about the `add_it` part where the function goes to `ptr[index++]` so the `index` will increment in the main under the for loop so the array can be populated?

Thanks guys! I'm just trying to learn and will appreciate any clarity

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct sdata{
    int brake_fluid_pressure;
    int electrical_power;
    int driver_brake_pressure;
    int pressure;
    float time;
} Data_slice;

Data_slice make(int f, int p, int d, int e, float t){
    Data_slice piece; //members for each type of data
    piece.brake_fluid_pressure = f;
    piece.pressure = p;
    piece.driver_brake_pressure = d;
    piece.electrical_power = e;
    piece.time = t;
    return piece;
}

int rand_gen(int min, int max);
int add_it(Data_slice * ptr, int size, int index);
void write_it(char *car_data, Data_slice ptr[], int size, int index);

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    Data_slice data[100];
    int i;
    int num = 0;

    for (i=0; i<1177; i++){
        num = add_it(data, 100, num);
    }

    write_it("car_data.txt", data, 100, num);
    return(0);
}

int rand_gen(int min, int max){
    return (rand() % (max + 1 - min)) + min; 
}

int add_it(Data_slice * ptr, int size, int index){
    Data_slice temp = make(rand_gen(20,30),
                           rand_gen(10, 15),
                           rand_gen(20,40),
                           rand_gen(10,100),
                           0);
    index = index % size; 
    ptr[index++] = temp; //THIS PART I DO NOT UNDERSTAND! 
    return index;
}

void write_it(char *car_data, Data_slice ptr[], int size, int index){
    FILE * fout = fopen("car_data.txt", "w");
    if(fout == NULL){
        printf("Error writing! Program will exit");
        exit(0);
    }
    int i, ind;
    float t = 0.1;
    for(i=index; i<index+size; i++){
        ind = i % size; 
        ptr[ind].time = t;
        fprintf(fout, "%5.1f%20d%20d%20d%20d\n", ptr[ind].time,
                ptr[ind].brake_fluid_pressure,
                ptr[ind].pressure,
                ptr[ind].driver_brake_pressure,
                ptr[ind].electrical_power);
        t += 0.1;
    }
    fclose(fout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`%` is the *modulus* operator. `index % size` returns the remainder of dividing `index` by `size`. This is used to make the index wrap around to `0` when it goes beyond the size of the array, and that's what makes the array "circular".

```
ptr[index++] = temp;
```

assigns `temp` to `ptr[index]`, and then increments `index`. This updated value of `index` is then returned by the function, and `main` assigns it back to the `num` variable.